# Unable to take webshot of a URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have been using node-webshot with one of my Sailsjs projects for quite sometime now. In that, I am using it to take a webshot of a route which has a view which contains dynamic graphs and charts created using google charts. The problem is, once the graph is generated(in this case, a bubble chart), the node-webshot method call generates an empty image of this page. But if I open the route in browser, it generates the graph perfectly.

This is the kind of graph that gets generated dynamically - http://jsbin.com/vewesafegi/edit?html,js,output

And this is the sails js node-webshot code I am using to generate its webshot.

```
    var options = {
        screenSize: {
            width: 710, 
            height: 500
        }, 
        shotSize: {
            width: 710,
            height: 'all'
        }, 
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B298g',
        siteType: 'url',
        renderDelay: 500,
        quality: 50
    };

    webshot('http://localhost:1337/generatedChart','Chart.png', options, function(err) {
        //do something
        res.ok();
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright...So I read the documentation of node-webshot and found out that in the `options` of webshot, I can set a key called `takeShotOnCallback` which if set to `true`, will allow me to have a callback(`window.callPhantom('takeShot');`) from the page once its loaded.

This callback will tell the webshot call to take the screenshot of the page.
More here - https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot#options

And the reason why the generated shot was blank was because the page wasnt loaded with the dynamically generated graphs at the time when the webshot was taken.